# Yii2 - User Is Logged Out After Logging In

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using standard way to login, but for some reason the session/login is not working as expected. As soon as user is redirected, the session will be destroyed, and the user won't stayed logged in.

Login:

```
public function actionLogin()
    {
        $model = new LoginForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            var_dump('<pre>', Yii::$app->user->identity , '</pre>');die;
            // $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->returnUrl);
        } else {

            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

(var_dump is providing the correct info for the user, which means that the user is logged in successfully).

**LoginForm model**:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    public $verifyCode;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // email and password are both required
            [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
            [['verifyCode'], 'required', 'when' => function () {
                return $this->captchaNeeded;
            }],
            [['verifyCode'], 'captcha', 'when' => function () {
                return $this->captchaNeeded;
            }],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'verifyCode' => 'Security code'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                //handle password retries and set captcha checker
                Yii::$app->session->set('_try_login', Yii::$app->session->get('_try_login', 0) + 1);
                //return error
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect email or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if captcha is needed.
     *
     * @return boolean whether the user try to login more than 2 times
     */
    public function getCaptchaNeeded()
    {
        return Yii::$app->session->get('_try_login', 0) > 2;
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided email and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[email]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {

        if ($this->_user === false)
            return User::findByEmail($this->email);


        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

User model is standard (it is quite large to post it here), but it is implementing IdentityInterface

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
```

Session is using db, and it is defined in the web.php (config file):

```
'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession'
        ],
```

Overall user model is working correctly, since if I try to login with wrong info, I will get a proper notification, and if I just render the page after the login (the validated login, I will get the proper header). Something is failing somewhere, and I can't figure it out what exactly.

I don't know it this does matter, I am using PHP version 7.0.15 (**PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 (cli) ( NTS )**), and Yii2 is 2.0.11.2.

Comment: Just idea, double check you are not regenerating session ID twice

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `$user->status = 10`
I had faced this problem. I changed user status from 0 to 10 on database and it worked.